# Update multi-value lookup column with Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, power-automate, multiple-values

I have two list:

1. Item List: contains beside the item name a column "item short" with a shortened string as our internal item registration text.
2. Main list: used like an inventory list. The item list is linked as a lookup column with multiple value input. The linked column is our "item short" text, an additional column shows the title column of the item list.

Now I want to populate the inventory from an Excel file. Besides other infos it contains a column with multiple item short names.

I found [this](https://tomriha.com/how-to-update-multiple-lookup-sharepoint-column-with-power-automate/) article but it is for the lookup column ID only and doesn't work with my item short.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand your question, you want to update you choice column (and its a multivalue one) in Power Automate, but you only got the value and not the id of the lookup items?

Why not just let your Power Automate flow lookup the values in the item list? The lookup id corresponds with the list item id.

Comment: This sounds good, simple and easy to use.